# What does mean the label generated from compiler?

Tags: assembly, gcc

compiler generates a gas, which has some strange labels (weird name) used for symbols:

```
.file   "a.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "string"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    call    puts@PLT
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0"
```

What is the `.LCO:`? label should end with semicolon `:`, directive should starts with dot `.`, so is it "label-directive"? and this name `.LC0`? Why isn't it name with the variable name? And in case of other symbols in other programs (not in this one particularly), the labels(directive?), will have names like `.LB0`, ... Are these names random?

Comment: Yes, they are random. [Labels beginning with `.L` are local symbols in gas for ELF](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html). It's unfortunate that they share namespace with the directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Lname` is a [GAS file-scope label](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html) (omitted from the `.o` symbol table, good for internal use within one object file).  There aren't any GAS directives that start with `.L`.

GCC uses `.L0` and upward auto-numbered labels for jump targets in code inside functions.

It uses `.LC0` and upward auto-numbered labels for read-only Constant data, like string literals, FP constants, and array initializers it wants to copy from with SIMD instead of storing as immediates.

> Why isn't it name with the variable name?

What variable name?  I assume you did `printf("string\n");` so it's an anonymous string literal.  If you had done this at global scope, you would get a `mystring:` label.

```
   static char mystring[] = "string";
```